Install failures on Ubuntu Server 24.04 ARM64 ISO install with autoinstall enabled
I have been working for a while to get a set of ISO installs working with various autoinstall parameters set.  I started with the 22.04 release and changed to 24.04 when it was released.
After much googling and find a whole lot of things that simply do not work I found some instructions for using the user-data file with autoinstall configured. When the issues stated I backed off to a version that is a few weeks old and has always installed with no issues.  I use a fair bit of everything:
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  user-data:
    runcmd:
      - lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
      - resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
      - ln -sf ../run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
      - timedatectl set-timezone America/Los_Angeles
      - /opt/firstboot/fb_set_hostname.sh
      - /opt/firstboot/fb_check_home_mount.sh
      - /opt/firstboot/fb_install_packages.sh
      - /opt/firstboot/fb_set_tuning.sh
    users:
      - name: mybuntu
        gecos: mybuntu Default User
        passwd: $6$51x1HNnSAXmw$........................giLFvlVF4oGsX7is0
        shell: /bin/bash
        lock-passwd: false
        groups: [sudo]
        sudo: 'ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL'
  interactive-sections:
    - network
    - storage
    - apt
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    install-server: true
  apt:
    disable_components: [restricted,multiverse]
    disable_suites: [backports,security]
    geoip: false
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
      - arches: [arm64]
        uri: http://local-mirror.com/ubuntu-ports
    preferences:
      - package: "*"
        pin: "release a=noble-updates"
        pin-priority: 200
    late-commands:
    - |
      rm /target/etc/apt/preferences.d/90curtin.pref
      true
  packages:
    - net-tools
  late-commands:
    # Make sure system will use the local apt mirror
    - sed -i /target/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources -e 's/ports.ubuntu.com/pnr-211-a05-r3.svceng.com/'
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- apt update
    # DHCP by MAC address instead of ssh host keys
    - /cdrom/postinstall/set_dhcp_by_mac.sh
    # set up the files required to tune the system during first boot
    - mkdir -p /target/opt/firstboot
    - cp /cdrom/postinstall/fb*.sh /target/opt/firstboot
    - chmod 755 /target/opt/firstboot/*
    # Work around: These should be apt installable from the ISO image pool and dists directories
    - cp -r /cdrom/debs /target
    - cp /cdrom/postinstall/install_common_debs.sh /target/debs
    - cp /cdrom/postinstall/install_xxx_modules.sh /target/debs
    # Install the SVT modules for this kernel
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- /debs/install_common_debs.sh
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- /debs/install_svt_modules.sh
    # Update grub to boot from Cobalt kernel
    - /cdrom/postinstall/update_grub_default.sh
    - /cdrom/postinstall/create_grubd_40_xxx.sh KERNEL_VERSION_STRING
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- update-grub

I did clean up a bit of the above but it should not affect the results. The point is this has worked for several weeks and no long works and I don't know why.
I have been making great progress to my targets but suddenly installs are always failing. There are various different error messages I will include but they seem to be around connections failures of some kind.  For example:
connecting...  
waiting for cloud-init...  
generating crash report
report saved to /var/crash/1724776173.102703810.ui.crash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1378, in _crn
    _, proto = await self._loop.create_unix_connection(
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 255, in create_unix_cn
    await self.sock_connect(sock, path)
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 501, in sock_connt
    return await fut
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 509, in _sock_cont
    sock.connect(address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/bin/subiquity", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/lib/python3.10/site-packages/subiquity/cmd/tui.py", line 158, in main
    asyncio.run(run_with_loop())
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_come
    return future.result()
  File "/snap
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ubuntu-server ttyAMA0

Another starts with:
connecting...  
waiting for cloud-init...  
generating crash report
report saved to /var/crash/1724777475.030085325.ui.crash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1378, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._loop.create_unix_connection(
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 255, in create_unix_connection
    await self.sock_connect(sock, path)
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 501, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 509, in _sock_connect
    sock.connect(address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

This one cascades down to the message:
    async with make_request(
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 199, in __aenter__
    return await anext(self.gen)
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/lib/python3.10/site-packages/subiquity/common/api/client.py", line 118, in make_request
    async with session.request(
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1138, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 535, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 542, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/snap/subiquity/5744/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1382, in _create_connection
    raise UnixClientConnectorError(self.path, req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.UnixClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to unix socket /run/subiquity/socket ssl:default [Connection refused]

I will admit I am an old kernel guy and only occasionally delve into python. Since I have started to understand the autoinstall mechanism I have not tried to undo and recreate any of the squashfs segments and would like to avoid it.
There have been other times when it got past these errors but the install just hung at some point with spinning indicators for 1 or 2 tasks.
It kind of seems to connection errors of some kind. Can anybody tell me what it is trying to connect to and failing? What could have caused this to suddenly have become an issue? Is there a way to enable debugging at this phase to get more information instead of just the python stack dump?
